# How to put numbers from one list to another?

Tags: python

I have two lists, I need to put in `list1[0][1]` and `list1[0][2] - list2[0][1]` and `list2[0][2]` and in `list1[1][1]` and `list1[1][2] - list2[0][1]` and `list2[0][2]`
how to make it with for loop(in future there will be more data, so I need loop)

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
list2 = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

I tried this code, but get stuck, understand that this is wrong

```
for i in list1:
    for k in list2:
        for l in list1[i-2:]:
            for m in i:
                m = 1
                list1.append(m)


print(list1)
```

want to have output like this:

```
list1 = [[1, 8, 9], [10, 11, 6]]
```

Comment: Please add your output and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Vignesh Rajendran sure, added

Comment: add your expected output also, how output list should look like

Comment: really difficult to image the output list from the question

Comment: @Vignesh Rajendran yeah, you right, easier to show than to write

Comment: @Nikolas can u rephrase your question?

Comment: @Nikolas you literaly need to replace list 2 with first and last element from list 1 , is that right?

Comment: I need to replace list 1 with first and last element from list 2, like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a work, hope it will help you out

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
list2 = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

a_list = list(range(1, length+1))

for l1, l2, size in zip(list1, list2, a_list):
    if size == 1:
        l2[0] = l1[0]
        temp1 = l2
        continue
    if size == len(list1):
        l2[-1] = l1[-1]
        temp2 = l2
        continue
    
list1 = [temp1, temp2]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will do the job. Note: both list must be of equal lengths.

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
list2 = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

def listOperation(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) == len(list2):
        list2[0][0] = list1[0][0]
        list2[len(list2)-1][-1] = list1[len(list1)-1][-1]
        return list2
        
    return 'Error'
    
print(listOperation(list1, list2))
```